# How to implement extended Lesk measure in Python for calculating word similarity?

Tags: python, similarity, words

I can't find the right code to implement the extended Lesk measure/ extended gloss overlap in Python. I have to calculate the similarity between word pairs and already did it with among other Lin, Wu-palmer, Resnik and path-similarities. But now I would like to try the extended Lesk measure.
Can someone help me?